# CSS - How to make a text to be shown under the center of an element, no matter how long the text is

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show three arrows, which their size can be changed.

Under those three arrows I'm trying to add a number underneath it. I want to make the numbers be at the center of the arrows no matter what their length will be.

And also I want that the whatever the different sizes of the arrows will be the numbers will be at the same height.

In order to do so I've tried the next code, but it sure doesn't seems to do the trick -

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        #container{
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
display: table;
}
#one{
width: 33%;
font-size: 90px;
}

#two{
width: 33%;
font-size: 50px;
}

#three{
width: 33%;
font-size: 60px;
}
#one,#two,#three{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


        #numbers {


        }


        .num {
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 50px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="one">&#9660;</div>
        <div id="two">&#9650;</div>
        <div id="three">&#9660;</div>
    </div>  

    <div id="numbers">
        <div class="num">8888</div>
        <div class ="num">88</divclass>
        <div class="num">8</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what can I do?

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean that you want each text placed right below the corresponding arrow-like symbol and centered horizontally with respect to it. Then you need to make the `#conrainer` and `#numbers` elements displayed as *rows* of the same table, not two independent tables. And you need a container for them, constituting the table (in CSS sense). You must not use `float` in such a context. Here’s a rather minimally modified version of your code, to implement this idea:

```html
<style>
#stuff {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#container{
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
display: table-row;
}
#one{
width: 33%;
font-size: 90px;
}

#two{
width: 33%;
font-size: 50px;
}

#three{
width: 33%;
font-size: 60px;
}
#one,#two,#three{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


#numbers {
  display: table-row;
}


        .num {
        width: 33%;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 50px;
        }
    </style>

<div id="stuff">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="one">&#9660;</div>
        <div id="two">&#9650;</div>
        <div id="three">&#9660;</div>
    </div>  

    <div id="numbers">
        <div class="num">8888</div>
        <div class="num">88</div>
        <div class="num">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```